# Add ASC / DESC to custom post columns

Tags: php, columns

Im using the following code to create custom columns in the backend of the posts menu.

```
add_filter('manage_edit-post_columns', 'post_edit_columns');
    function post_edit_columns( $columns )
    {
        $columns = array(
            'cb'            => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'title'         => 'Module Title',
            'categories'    => 'Section',
            'menu_order'    => 'Order',
            'unlock'        => 'Unlock',
            'date'          => 'Date'
        );
        return $columns;
    }
```

The `title` column outputs an ASC / DESC link. How can i add this ordering link to the other columns?

Comment: check out this tutorial: http://scribu.net/wordpress/custom-sortable-columns.html

Comment: @Milo please move your solution to an answer

Answer (score -1):

There is a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/) that let's you add/remove columns, and makes them sort. You dont need any coding.